# Why i'm getting the error "HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Integer."

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

I am getting the following error,

```
"HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Integer."
```

My `MySQL` tables looks like below,

**Employee**

[image]

**Employer**

[image]

My JPA Entities are below,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
private Integer id;

@JoinColumn(name = "employer_id", nullable = false)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Employer employer;

getter and setter ....
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employer")
 public class Employer implements java.io.Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
@NotNull
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "city")
@Size(max = 16)
private String city;

getter and setter...
}
```

My server log shows error,

```
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
at com.mycompany.server.facade.EmployeeFacade.getEmployeesByEmployer(EmployeeFacade.java:38)
```

My facade class is,

```
    line 35: public List<Employee> getEmployeesByEmployer(@NotNull Employer employer) {
line 36:     return getEntityManager().createQuery("from Employee where employer.id = :employerId").
line 37:             setParameter("employerId", employer.getId()).
line 38:             getResultList();
line 39: }
```

I'm getting this error while trying to access the facade method from my Employers rest resource.
Please help me with the details provided.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing more than a wild guess; AFAIK number(9) will always fit into a java Integer, but number(10) will not.

Try lowering the length of your int's to 9 (or lower) digits.